# Can't use redis with nodejs 18.13. Invalid or unexpected token?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

Nodejs Application Crashes by only importing redis.

[image]

Error:

```
/Users/debanjantewary/Desktop/YSG/server/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/cluster/cluster-slots.js:65
            if (node.client.options?.readonly)
                                    ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Tried solution But didn't work:

1. Clear cache node
2. Re-install Node stable version

Please help If anyone knows. Thank you ❤️

Comment: Which version of node are you using and which version of Redis? Seems like `optional-chaining` feature is not supported by your node.

Comment: I am using node 18.13 in my system  `❯ node -v
v18.13.0`,     `"redis": "^4.5.1"`

Comment: Share more code where you used redis and the full error message. The error message tells you which line of the code is causing the error.

Comment: [error_file_github](https://github.com/DebanjanT/debug/blob/main/redis_error.js)  this is the index file of my application , I am not using redis anywhere just importing it throwing this error

Comment: welp, running into the same problem.